# android - ScrollView fills all the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

my view contains a ScrolView with several views inside, and another LinearLayout with the id "bottom_view".
the problem is, that if the ScrolView contains many views, it hides the "bottom_view" LinearLayout.

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder"

            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dialog_text_layout_name"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_text_product_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:text="name" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/dialog_text_layout_name"

                >

                <com.parse.ParseImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_row_logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:src="@drawable/no_image"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:visibility="visible">
                </com.parse.ParseImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="24sp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="מחיר"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="#FF8000"

                    >
                </TextView>
            </FrameLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_text_product_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="אין תיאור"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_text_business_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="מחסני חשמל"
                android:textColor="#FF8000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="יפו 30 ירושלים"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
                android:orientation = "horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_telephone_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="03-1234567"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_telephone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="טלפון: "/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45sp"
                android:orientation = "horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_text_distance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="מרחק לא ידוע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation = "vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_open_hours"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="שעות פתיחה"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_open_hours_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="אין מידע"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
    android:background="@drawable/my_black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/phone"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/share_btn"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/images"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/images"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight= "1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/home_con_white"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ScrollView` layout height to:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
```

The problem was that `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` had `match_parent` height and it force the `ScrollView` to take the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView and layout with "cancel" button below

```
LayoutParams scrollViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
scrollViewLayoutParams.setMargins(0,
                            convertToDp(10),
                            0,
                            convertToDp(50)); // 50dp - place for button
scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollViewLayoutParams);
parentView = (ViewGroup) scrollView.getParent(); // parent FrameLayout
parentView.addView(cancelButtonLayout);
```

ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

"cancel" button layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    >
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                    android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnWKR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> android:fillViewport="true"

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:fillViewport="true"
    >
```